# Windows Server 2012

Tags: windows, vpn, windows-server-2012, windows-server-2012-r2

[image: Photo of the power managment]

I have a really annoying problem.

When I start my server (it is for test purposes, so its on a laptop) and I leave the remote connection and not use it for a while, it will disconnect me.

It will not reconnect unless I move my mouse a little (then it starts to reconnect).

It is really annoying since when I am at a remote location I cannot move the mouse and it will disconnect.

The VPN will also stop working then.

Can anyone help me to resolve this issue?

Edit: I'm also still learning at the moment so please help me with steps :)

Comment: 1) Make sure your laptop isn't going to sleep or any other power state (a server is usually supposed to be on 24/7). 2) your VPN, is your server your VPN server, or some other device (your router, perhaps)? If it is and the laptop is going to sleep, then this would also answer why your VPN drops.

Comment: Also make sure your laptop network connections are always on - Network and Sharing Center on your Server 2012 can let you configure the adapter power settings.

Comment: @BigChris i've checked your theory on the network and sharing setting but i've already unchecked the box "Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power" so that doesnt fix it. my VPN is made on the server and i am connected through WIFI. also included an photo

Comment: What about your laptop power settings so that it doesn't go to sleep or hibernate etc.?

Comment: @BigChris thats all turned off

Comment: Can you install a backup service like [TeamViewer](http://www.teamviewer.com) to reconnect to your server if the VPN drops out?

Comment: Any incoming and outcoming connection will turn off, so that doesn't solve it :S